# How to correctly setup Global Site Tag (gtag.js) for user_id tracking

Tags: python, django, google-analytics

I'm trying to implement user_id tracking on my website. I send emails to users with a `user_id` in their personal link which I need to track. As per the documentation I have added to `gtag.js`.

```
gtag('config', 'MY_GA_MEASUREMENT_ID', {
  'user_id': 'USER_ID'
});
```

When I go to my website with the following parameters `?&user_id=1` I check my Tag Assistent to see which parameters are set and I see the following:

```
user_id = -1
uid = USER_ID
```

Yet my user-id view only shows visits from `uid=USER_ID`. Whereas I need to see `user_id=-1`. Does anyone have a clue about how to tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace the string 'USER_ID' in the code with your value:

```
gtag('config', 'MY_GA_MEASUREMENT_ID', {
  'user_id': '-1'
});
```

In other words, you need retrieve the data from the parameter in URL and write it in the code so page is executed it sends that value to Google Analytics (instead of the string 'USER_ID' which is the example of the documentation...).